# How to make Navicat mySQL (Non-Commercial) tables default to InnoDB engine?

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam, navicat

I have Navicat mySQL Non-Commercial version. Whenever I create a table, it defaults to the myISAM storage engine for each new table , how do I make tables default to InnoDB engine without having to explicitly select these for each new table creation?

I'm trying to make this the default engine on Navicat without having to navigate to any configuration files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There wouldn't be a Navicat setting for this.  The *default storage engine* is actually a configuration on the MySQL server.

The standard value for the default is MyISAM, though [it can be changed](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/storage-engine-setting.html).  This requires changing the default on the entire server (which you likely cannot do if you don't own the database server).

Answer (score 1):

At the top of your script for creating the database / tables use this flag:

```
SET storage_engine=INNODB;
```

See [MySQL Setting the Storage Engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/storage-engine-setting.html)

Comment: This is a question about a Navicat setting, not a mySQL setting